# How plotting a curve with vertical and oblique asymptote?

Tags: graphics

How can I plot a curve with a vertical and oblique asymptote, same as the following picture?

Curve equation: 
`y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^7+3x^6-2x^5-x^4-3x^2+1}{x^4-2x^2}}`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! You can achieve this e.g. with pgfplots. What have you tried?

Comment: I was looking in the [pgfplots gallery](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) for some example that looked like what you're asking, but I didn't find anything like that, however you can check for yourself if you want.

Nevertheless I don't understand your question, you can graph those kind of equations in the software you prefer and place the image in your LaTeX document.

Comment: you're right. But I dont know which software can do exactly the same thing that I showed by the picture.

Comment: @MaryamAmini You drew the figure with a software, didn't you? Then you can include this figure to your document, or use the software to export your figure to a Ti*k*Z or Asymptote code.

Answer (score 4):

It is true that you can draw the figure with other software and this has certainly some advantages. But you can also draw it with LaTeX, and then you do not have to worry to add equations to it. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459883/121799) is an extended discussion of this topic.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
    f(\x)=pow((x^7+3*x^6-2*x^5-x^4-3*x^2+1)/(x^4-2*x^2),1/3);}]
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=5,ymin=-0.5,ymax=6,xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$},grid=major,
   title={$\displaystyle f(x)=\sqrt[3]{\frac{x^7+3x^6-2x^5-x^4-3x^2+1}{x^4-2x^2}}$}]
    \addplot[color=blue,semithick,domain={sqrt(2.035)}:5,samples=71] {f(x)}
    node[pos=0.75,above,sloped]{$y=f(x)$};
    \addplot[color=blue,semithick,domain=0.55:1.11,samples=71] {f(x)};
    \addplot[color=green!70!black,domain=0:5,samples=2] {x}
    node[midway,below,sloped]{$y=x$};
    \addplot[color=green!70!black,domain=-0.5:6,samples=2] ({sqrt(2)},{x})
    node[midway,above,sloped]{$x=\sqrt{2}$};
    \addplot[color=red!70!black,domain=0:5,samples=2] {1.075};
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your great help

Comment: @MaryamAmini If the answer works for you, could you please consider [accepting it](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/121799)?

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,svgnames, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usepackage{pst-plot, multido}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\def\f{((x^7 + 3*x^6-2*x^5-x^4-3*x^2 + 1)/(x^4-2*x^2))^(1/3)}
\def\g{-((x^7 + 3*x^6-2*x^5-x^4-3*x^2 + 1)/(2*x^2- x^4))^(1/3)}

\begin{document}

\psset{plotstyle=curve, algebraic, arrowinset=0.15, dx=2,Dx = 2}%
\psset{subgriddiv=2,gridcolor=LightSteelBlue, subgridcolor=LightSteelBlue!40, yunit=1.25}
\sffamily
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.8)(8.5, 6.5)
\psclip{\psframe(-0.5,-0.8)(8.5,6.5)}
\psgrid[xunit=2, yunit=2, gridlabels=0pt, subgriddiv = 4]
\psaxes[labels=none, arrows=->, arrowscale=1.3, xsubticks=4, ysubticks=2, subtickcolor=black](0,0)(7.5,5.8)[$x$,-130] [$y$,-40]%
\uput[r](0,2){2.688}\uput[r](0,4){5.375}\uput{12pt}[l](8.5,2){2.688}\uput{12pt}[l](8.5,4){5.375}
 \psplot[plotpoints=10, linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=DodgerBlue]{0.549631}{1.103438}{\f}
 \psplot[plotpoints=10, linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=DodgerBlue]{0.41}{0.54963}{\g}
 \psplot[plotpoints=10, linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=DodgerBlue]{1.103439}{1.414}{\g}
\psplot[plotpoints=200, linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=DodgerBlue]{1.418}{8}{\f}
\psline[linecolor=LightSeaGreen](1.4,-1)(1.4,8)
\psline[linecolor=LightSeaGreen](0,0)(8,8)
\multido{\n = -0.5 + 0.5}{16}{\psline[linewidth=0.3pt](\n, -0.8)(\n, -0.65)\psline[linewidth=0.3pt](\n, 6.5)(\n, 6.35)%
 \psline[linewidth=0.3pt](-0.5, \n)(-0.35,\n) \psline[linewidth=0.3pt](8.5, \n)(8.35,\n)}
\multido{\i = 0 + 2}{5}{\uput{10pt}[d](\i, 0){\i}\psline(\i, -0.8)(\i, -0.6)%
\psline(-0.5,\i)(-0.25,\i)\psline(8.5,\i)(8.25,\i)
\uput{11pt}[d](\i, 6.5){\i}\psline(\i, 6.5)(\i,6.3)}
\endpsclip
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]