# Why Tikz instead of EPS or PDF

Tags: tikz-styles, eps

Although I am new to latex, I noticed most of the authors are using tikz related packages to produce the figures.

Why can't we use EPS or PDF format? I hope EPS or PDF are easy to produce the figures. Please suggest.

Comment: EPS or PDF are formats of the produced files when you use TeX/LaTeX packages like Tikz to draw what you need to.

Comment: The fonts of annotations in the tikzpicture match the one of the ambient document, and you can easily add equations/math content in the nodes. Note that your question is almost completely identical to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459883, where you can find more reasons in the answers.

Comment: EPS and PDF are file formats for representing images. They can not produce any image. However,  in LaTeX  you can use any image in those formats. Just include them with `\includegraphics{<image file name>}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An EPS file or a PDF file *are* figures created by some software. They create nothing by themselves.

On the other hand, with TikZ you can create pictures with commands which are part of the `.tex` file that you are working with.